# pygtk how to limit line length in gtk.TextView

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I'm building a GUI in which I need to allow the user to enter text in a TextView, but I need to limit each line of text to 70 characters or less.

using python + pygtk.

Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [insert-text signal of GtkTextBuffer](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextbuffer.html#signal-gtktextbuffer--insert-text) and remove the excess characters.

Sample code in C:
http://www.gtkforums.com/about1012.html

Comment: The C code is a bit more than I can understand, however, looking at the textbuffer API, I found that I can use the get_end_iter().get_chars_in_line() condition to find out if I'm over my per-line limit. All of this in the event you suggested. The problem now is truncating the text instead of just delting it. I'd like to word-wrap it so that it does not exceed 70 characters per line.

Comment: If all you want is wrapping, you can set a width for the container of the TextView and then use [gtk.TextView.set_wrap_mode(wrap_mode)](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktextview.html#method-gtktextview--set-wrap-mode) to enable the
type of wrapping you want. If the 70 char limit is vital, then as far as I know, some type of callback function has to be coded. You can find info on how to manipulate text from the text buffer at a specific location by reading [tutorial on text buffers](http://www.moeraki.com/pygtktutorial/pygtk2tutorial/sec-TextBuffers.html). Hope this helps in some way.